# ¿Cómo compartir en whatssap una url con parámetros?

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, visual-studio

Al utilizar el botón de compartir en whatsapp no consigo que me lea el parámetro  ID=111 que tiene mi url.

Esta es mi url: href=https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=https://www.mipaginaweb.com?id=1111

Solo muestra como se evidencia en la imagen la url principal pero no el parámetro, alguien sabe como hacerlo?

Saludos 
[[image: Error no muestra la url completa[1]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digo yo que será:

```
href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mipaginaweb.com%26id%3D1111"
```

Más info aquí: https://www.xatakandroid.com/comunicacion-y-mensajeria/asi-puedes-compartir-un-numero-de-whatsapp-y-un-mensaje-a-traves-de-un-enlace

Url formateada con esto: https://www.freeformatter.com/url-encoder.html

Comment: Hola que pena ya le hago la corrección igual sigue igual enviado como aparece en la imagen

Comment: Gracias pero igual si evidencias no toma nada despues del = toma los demas !"#$%&/ pero igual no lo toma y no se el porque

Comment: Tienes que poner &, el ? solo se puede usar una vez

Comment: Solucionado ? Te he editado la respuesta @Richard Rodriguez

Comment: Le agrego lo que me comentas y corta la url o me estoy equivocando si lo puedes mostrar en un ejemplo el código como quedaría o si me estoy equivocando por q lo que evidencio solo comparte https://www.mipaginaweb.com le falta el id=1111

Comment: Te lo he puesto en mi respuesta :(

Comment: Si que pena pero evidencio que solo deja https://www.mipaginaweb.com y le falta el id=1111 si no me sigue dirigiendo a mi pagina principal y no a la del ID @Daniel Díaz

Comment: Ahora, mira la respuesta

Comment: Listo super bien voy a implementar en mi desarrollo espero que no salga nada raro